# looking for an easy switch between "write to STDOUT" and "write to outfile"

Tags: perl, io

for a program i am trying to write in perl right now, i want to build in an option that makes the output go to an output file, which is pretty easy with the perl module Getopt. however, if the option is not used, i would like the output to go to the terminal (STDOUT). for that i wrote a little script to test if i could build a switch with the module IO::File.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use IO::File;

my $outfilename;

GetOptions (
    "out=s" => \$outfilename,
);

my $out = IO::File->new(">$outfilename");

if (defined $out) {
    print $out "Hello World!\n";
}
else {
    print "Hello World!\n";
}

close $out if $outfilename;
```

although the program "runs" with or without a -o option, when i run it without -o, perl tells me that $outfilename in line 13 is not initialized, which i guess is because Getopt returns variables as "false" when the option is not used. however, i cannot think of a way to circumvent this. can you guys help me out?
also, i am absolutely sure that there is a much easier way to build in such a switch that i am not aware of. i was just writing this because i couldn't find any better way online, so if you guys have any tips on how to do that smarter, i would be very grateful!

Comment: I don't know if you know this, because I saw you trying to accept more than one answer, but you can only select one answer to your question.

Comment: yes :D i just realized that, and i don't like it because i think that all answaers are pretty useful here.

Comment: Yes, answers in the Perl tag generally speaking holds a high quality, and as you can see, it is also peer reviewed actively, as can be noted in our discussion in the comments. I would say that the "best" solution is probably ikegami's first. Not because of the reasons he states, but because it is more transparent: `print $outfh "stuff"` clearly tells anyone reading the code what is going on, whereas `print "stuff"` can be confusing.

Comment: changed the accepted answer. ;) forgive me if i stray off the topic of this post, but this is one of the many reasons i like learning how to perl. so many skilled and helpful people in this forum (although speaking as a very new perl writer: sometimes "too" skilled ;) )

Comment: It is easy to lose sight of how it was to not understand Perl, yes. :D Something that seems self-evident might be quite confusing to a new user. But that is also a good thing about this site, that it helps the experts learn how to explain things to newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the warning because you use `$outfilename` as a file name unconditionally even though it only has a value when `--out` has been provided.

Don't put the entire `print` in the `if`. You end up with lots of duplicated code if you do that. Either create a file handle that's initialized under all conditions

```
my $outfh;
if (defined($outfilename)) {
   open($outfh, '>', $outfilename)
      or die($!);
} else {
   $outfh = \*STDOUT;
}

print $outfh "Hello World!\n";
```

or redirect STDOUT

```
if (defined($outfilename)) {
   open(STDOUT, '>', $outfilename)
      or die($!);
}

print "Hello World!\n";
```

But why aren't you redirecting STDOUT from the outside?

```
script >script.log
```

Comment: Or use `select` to set the output filehandle.

Comment: @TLP, I disagree. There's no indication that there's any need for `select` and the problems it brings.

Comment: oh...god, thanks a lot, that is good to know! so IO::File is not really necessary, or even "in the way" here? also, how would you close this file, given that it is only opened under a certain condition? i am asking, because for the real program, the files it is going to create are pretty big, and i would like to relieve the workspace whenever i can.

Comment: `open` is more capable at no cost, and it the handles it creates are also IO::File objects. // Files get closed automatically on exit. The only reason to call `close` would be to check for errors. You'd use `close(STDOUT) or warn($!);`

Comment: Is there a way to recover STDOUT after `open(STDOUT, '>', $outfilename)`?

Comment: @mpapec, No, no more than with `script >script.log`. If you want a function to write to a file, I suggest passing a file handle to it (as created using the first snippet). If you have to deal with an existing poorly written function, I recommend IO::Capture.

Comment: perhaps local *STDOUT before `open()`

Comment: @mpapec, You could that or `select`, but those aren't my recommendations.

Comment: as to why i don't redirect STDOUT from the outside: i can see that giving an option to to redirect STDOUT while passing STDOUT to the terminal if the option isn't used is basically the same as giving no option for that and letting the user pass the output to a file externally. I was just wondering if it can be done, though; and also, if i write a program that has an option to create an output file (with Getopt::Long), and the option is ignored, the program would return an error, which i didn't like

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to set the default output file handle. This will make `print` automatically print to the `select`ed file handle.

```
if ($outfilename) {
    open my $outfh, ">", $outfilename 
       or die "Cannot open $outfilename for output: $!";
    select $outfh;
}

print "Hello world!\n";
```

Comment: That will break under some conditions (e.g. output of children won't be redirected). My solution redirects fd1, so it doesn't have those problems.

Comment: So you are saying that `select` should never be used?

Comment: No. I'm just saying there's no indication that there's any need for `select` and the problems it brings.

Comment: And what would constitute a need for `select`, in your opinion?

Comment: I'll let you know when I find one.

Comment: So, in other words, you do not know of any need to use `select`, which is what I said earlier: You are saying one should never use `select`. Do you have a motivation for this?

Comment: You mean aside from the aforementioned problems and aforementioned lack of need? No, that's probably it.

Comment: @ikegami I just ran a test on your claim, and both parent and child wrote to the `select`ed file. Is this system specific? Do you have something I can read on the topic?

Comment: `select` only affects Perl variables, not the system. As soon as you leave the interpreter, it's invisible. `perl -e'open my $fh, ">", "foo" or die $!; select($fh); system("echo foo");'`

Comment: @ikegami Well, that is sort of misleading, isn't it? `system` uses the terminal output, and we were talking about Perl's standard output. Anyone who knows what they are doing would never use `system` to capture output.

Comment: WTF? What are you talking about? Who said anything "using `system` to capture output"???? What's that got to do with anything???? What does that even mean????

Comment: @ikegami You should probably try to relax. It looks like you are about to pop a blood vessel. This is just programming, not the end of the world.

Comment: huh? Confusion at the total nonsense of a comment does not indicate stress. What did you actually mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace STDOUT with your filehandle, and then print normally.

```
if($outfilename) {
    open my $of, ">", $outfilename;
    *STDOUT = $of;
}

print "Hello World!\n";
```

Comment: Or you can just `select $of` without needing to destroy the standard output handle.

Comment: Both of those solutions (assigning to `*STDOUT` and `select`) will break in some conditions (e.g. output of children won't be redirected). My solution redirects fd1, so it doesn't have those problems.

Answer (score -1):

You'd better take a look at the following:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/SelectSaver.html

The `select`call lets you redefine what is the default file handler for the `print` calls.
`SelectSaver` lets you do the same thing in the scope of a given block of code.

In your case you could rewrite your code so that you create the output file handle if needed and `select` it, before running the code that will do the output. The outputting code, in turn, would just call `print` without file handle.

Comment: That will break under some conditions (e.g. output of children won't be redirected). My solution redirects fd1, so it doesn't have those problems.

Comment: @ikegami Did the OP talk about a child process ? NO ! You're answering a question which is not asked. Please respect the rules.

Comment: You're free to use the more complicated buggy solution if you want, but recommending it to others is another story.